# MongoDB .GetDatabase yields "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property"

Tags: c#, mongodb

Using MongoDB C# driver 2.4.2, try to establish some reference but getting the err for the last line regarding **_db**.

"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property CurrentClassName._client"

Can't figure it out.

Code:

```
public class MongoDatabase<T> : ImyDB<T> where T : class, new()
{
private static string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
private string _dbName;
private MongoClient _client = new MongoClient(_connectionString);
private IMongoDatabase _db = _client.GetDatabase(_dbName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `_client` field in the initializer of `_db` field. From C# specification [10.4.5.2 Instance field initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx)

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the
>   instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name.

You can move both initializations to constructor, or at least you should move `_db` initialization there:

```
public MongoDatabase()
{
   _client = new MongoClient(_connectionString);
   _db = _client.GetDatabase(_dbName);
}
```

I would also consider injection `client` into your class, and moving config-reading responsibility to your IoC containter configuration.